# Why doesn't this ActiveRecord SQL != query do the opposite of the equivalent = query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following piece of AR/SQL code returning the following value:

`Post.joins(:comments).uniq.count # => 20`

When I refine it as below, I get the reduced value I would expect:

`Post.joins(:comments).uniq.where('comments.user_id = ?', user.id).count # => 9`

So when I run the same code but with the match negated, I would expect the to get the opposite bunch of records - ie a count of 11. But instead I get this:

`Post.joins(:comments).uniq.where('comments.user_id != ?', user.id).count # => 20`

I want to say, basically "Find all posts with comments where the comment was made by someone other than ."

Have I misunderstood how negation behaves in SQL?

I should specify that I'm using Rails 3.2.18, which doesn't seem to allow the `where.not()` syntax I found in the Rails guide (it raises ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)).

Comment: Um, I've always used `<>` for negation in SQL.  I somehow had the impression that `!=` doesn't work.

Comment: FYI guides on Rails 3 are located [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/).

Answer (score 2):

The second query is actually responding to the question: Find all posts with at least one comment not made by ...
So it looks like your user has commented in 9 posts. But someone else has also made a comment in those posts.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the problem, but I still can't figure out how to write the statement that would return 'all posts with no comments made by...'

Answer (score 0):

Works as intended for me...

One thing I've noticed is that your queries are different, *.user_id* and *comments.user_id*

```
Post.joins(:comments).uniq.where('.user_id = ?', user.id).count # => 9
Post.joins(:comments).uniq.where('comments.user_id != ?', user.id).count # => 20
```